# A sample, a sampling, samplings

Tags: grammar

1. We've got a sample for that.
2. We've got a sampling for that.
3. We've got samplings for that.

What are the differences between a sample, a sampling, and samplings? 
Are they completely interchangeable?

Comment: **Samplings** is just the plural of **sampling**. There are separate dictionary entries for [sample](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sample) and [sampling.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sampling) Please add to your question by telling us what you don't understand about these definitions. The difference is small, and they are interchangeable in some cases, but not all. _NOTE:_ As you see in your dictionary, both nouns usually take the preposition **of**, not **for**, and certainly would in your sentences.

Comment: @P.E.Dant: regarding **of** and **for**, it depends on what **that** represents. If, for example it represents something to be sampled, for example  **blood**, then **of** is, as you say, the right preposition. If **that** represents a parameter that a sample is required for its measurement, for example **heamoglobin**, then **for** is the right preposition.

Comment: @Javalatte I could create a scenario that justifies the use of **with** or **under** as well, but it seems to me that our objective here is to help learners achieve natural speech and usage. I haven't verified this, but my guess is that _sampling for_ returns a nearly flat line. My comment, though, should have substituted _probably_ for _certainly,_ if only on the principle that it's always safer to equivocate.